# How to make post Masonry grid image responsive in mobile and PC by CSS code

Tags: html, css, masonry

I have problem with image in page from website please click on [link](https://nourena.com/%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7/) and check the sample page image in post Masonry grid. Image works good in PC but in mobile it is not responsive. Also I make css code for every images:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

but nothing work with this page.

Comment: Please add all the HTML, JavaScript and CSS that describes the problem into the question, using the code formatting tools. We try to discourage questions in the form of "please see my site", as once the issue it is fixed, the question is not useful as a learning resource for future readers.

Comment: i am sorry , but i can not find the right code for these problems from website

Comment: please help me only for this case , and i promise you i will not ask here without code

Comment: All you need to do is copy what you have. Since, presumably, you wrote the site as it stands, you know what items to copy. Additionally, if you like, you can supply a JS Fiddle.